# How do I connect a media server to 3 LANs?

Tags: networking, lan, home-networking

I'm planning to connect a media server (Raspberry pi may be) to 3 separate home networks (with separate subnets). I've researched and found solutions for 2 networks. If it's possible, how do I go about connecting 3 networks to the server? I can keep the server in one of the networks or in totally separate network. Also, the computers/devices should not be able to access devices from other networks. Devices should have access to devices in its own subnet and the server.

Comment: Setup a VPN server for the network the media server is in, and from the other networks, connect to it via VPN. Then it doesn't matter where the other networks are.

Comment: Are they in the same home or different physical locations? What soultion did you find for 2 networks? If it handles two, it should handle more.

Comment: Will that be over the internet? Bcz that will waste a lot of internet bandwidth. I forgot to mention all 3 home networks and server network are nearby.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch they are in neighboring houses, so they can be connected with Ethernet. The solution I found was connecting both via switch, then route forwarding settings in both the routers. But this method will give all devices access to each other.

Comment: I meant devices will get access to other networks' devices, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a router between the 3 networks. Most routers that aren't bottom-tier are capable of handling multiple networks – be it OpenWRT, a Mikrotik, an ER-X/ER-L, Raspberry Pi, etc.

Each network's existing main router should have a static route for the other two networks, pointing to the 'new' router as the gateway.

Nearly all routers come with firewalls. Edit the firewall rules such that only traffic to your media server is allowed (plus "established" traffic so that replies can go back).

The mechanism doesn't really change much from 2 to higher numbers. (But in all cases, there is the requirement that all networks have unique addresses: you *cannot* reliably connect two 192.168.1.x/24's together.)

Comment: Thanks. All three networks have their own internet. So pointing to new router as gateway will prevent internet access, right? I guess firewall is the key here, that should work perfectly. I will have to check firewall supported routers.

Comment: @HimanshuMehani: Don't point to the new router as the _main_ gateway! Point to the new router as a gateway for _the other two networks,_ nothing more.

Comment: Would you mind explaining this?

Comment: That's probably worth its own thread, but in short: routers (and even computers) can have a 'routing table' which lists several different gateways for different destinations. (And that's why the default gateway is called "default gateway".) Most routers let you add custom routes like "192.168.3.xx can be reached via 192.168.1.23".